# Difference between git push -u and git push -f?

Tags: git, github, push, commit

I know a push is after commit but I continue to get an error after I used command "git push -u origin master". The error reads as follows:

! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ . . .'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I then used "git push -f origin master" and the command worked. So what is the difference here? I'm not understanding documentation and videos haven't been as helpful.

Comment: The answers given thus far were correct except every time I tried to push I got an error with possible reasons being: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details. . . . . I ended up using Git push -f origin master and that worked perfectly. SO WHAT JUST HAPPENED?

Comment: Did you search before asking?

Comment: Your question indicates a lack of searching, which is why I asked. There's no need to be rude; a basic search should have provided you with the necessary commands to create a commit.

Comment: Still not getting the documentation on push -f and -u. If you have a dumbed down way of explaining it I'd GREATLY appreciate it!

Comment: pull the remote changes into your current branch (master).

Answer (score 1):

The error message already given you the hint:

There are extra changes in remote, and you need to pull the changes into your own repo, add your changes upon it, and push.

To illustrate the problem:

It starts with this:

```
Remote:
             [master]
            /
A <- B <- C

Local:
             [master]
            /
A <- B <- C
```

You have done some changes locally, and someone else done some changes in remote

```
Remote:
                       [master]
                      /
A <- B <- C <- D <- E

Local:
                 [master]
                /
A <- B <- C <- X
```

Just imagine, if you push your change to remote, what will remote looks like?  Git wouldn't guess it for you, so you need to deal with it locally, smoothen everything out, and then push:

```
Remote:
                       [master]
                      /
A <- B <- C <- D <- E

Local:
                      [origin/master]
                     /
A <- B <- C <- D <- E
           ^    
            \-- X 
                 \
                   [master]
```

Then either merge or rebase it:

(In case of merge)

```
                [origin/master]   [master]
                     /            /
A <- B <- C <- D <- E <--------- Y
           ^                   /
            \-- X <-----------/
```

(In case of rebase)

```
                [origin/master]   [master]
                     /            /
A <- B <- C <- D <- E <--------- X'
```

In both case, it will allow you to push, as your local master branch is a decedent of remote's master, for which remote's master can fast-forward to.

If you use `push -f` instead, you will simply force the remote to take your `[master]`, in the above case, remote's master will become your `X` commit, and commits `D` and `E` will be lost.  Usually it is something you don't want, especially it is the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Commit your changes with a message

```
git commit -m "Your commit message here"
```

And then push to origin (if you have configured the origin properly, and if pushing to master branch.)

```
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Next step is committing you're changes. `git add` just added them to the staging. Then you need to commit them in which you'll run `git commit -m "Message when committing"`. The message will display on your commit message. Then run `git push` will put all your changes to the repository.

Please refer to the documentation of git for further understanding.

> For adding them to the staging.
>   https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add
>
> For committing them
>   https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit
>
> When pushing to the repo
>   https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Answer (score 0):

`git add .` will not commit your changes, It'll only stage them. If we were to assume your local branch is up to date with the remote and you performed:

```
git add .
git push
```

Nothing would happen as you have no new commits to push.

`git push -u origin master` will attempt to push your local branch named `master` to the remote named `origin`. It's almost certain that `origin` will already have a branch named `master` so you're effectively trying to replace it. If you ran the same command with `-f` (force), you would replace it.